# PDE separation of variables, weird textbook example

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Getting a good grasp of these type of questions now but the end of this one is tripping me up a bit.

**Question**: Use separation of variables to find a product solution for the partial differential equation

$$y*∂_{xy}u + u = 0,$$

where u is a function of x and y.

---

My attempt:

Substitute $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ into the PDE to obtain

$$yX'Y'+XY=0$$

Then using separation of variables and the separation constant $-\lambda,$

$$ \frac{X'}{X}=\frac{-Y}{yY'}=-\lambda$$

So we have

$$X'=-\lambda X,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ Y'=\frac{1}{\lambda y}Y$$

which according to the textbook has these solutions:

$$X=c_1e^{-\lambda x},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ Y=c_2y^{1/\lambda}.$$

with the product solution

$$u=XY=c_3e^{-\lambda x}y^{1/\lambda}.$$

Now I understand the solution for $X$, but I cannot figure out how to obtain $c_2y^{1/\lambda}$ for $Y$. I think the starting point is  $$Y=c_2e^{(1/\lambda y)*y} $$

but that doesn't seem to get me there unless I've missed something really obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ Y'=\frac{1}{\lambda y}Y$$
$$ \frac   {Y'}Y=\frac{1}{\lambda y}$$
Integrate
$$ \int \frac   {dY}Y=\int \frac{dy}{\lambda y}$$
$$ \ln(Y)=\frac 1 {\lambda} \ln (y) +K$$
$$Y(y)=e^{1/\lambda(\ln(y)+K)}$$
$$Y(y)=Cy^{1/\lambda}$$

Answer (score 2):

To derive

$Y = c_2 y^{1/\lambda} \tag 1$

from

$Y' = \dfrac{dY}{dy} = \dfrac{1}{\lambda y} Y, \tag 2$

write it as

$(\ln Y)' = \dfrac{Y'}{Y} = \dfrac{1}{\lambda y} = \dfrac{1}{\lambda} \dfrac{1}{y} = \dfrac{1}{\lambda} (\ln y)'; \tag 3$

we integrate from $y_0$ to $y$:

$\ln Y(y) - \ln Y(y_0) = \displaystyle \int_{y_0}^y (\ln Y(z))' \; dz =  \dfrac{1}{\lambda} \int_{y_0}^y (\ln z)' \; dz =  \dfrac{1}{\lambda} (\ln y - \ln y_0);  \tag 4$

or

$\ln \left ( \dfrac{Y(y)}{Y(y_0)} \right ) = \dfrac{1}{\lambda} \ln \left ( \dfrac{y}{y_0} \right ) = \ln \left ( \dfrac{y^{1/\lambda}}{y_0^{1/\lambda}} \right ), \tag 5$

whence

$Y(y) = \dfrac{Y(y_0)}{y_0^{1/\lambda}} y^{1/\lambda} = c_2 y^{1/\lambda}, \tag 6$

where

$c_2 = \dfrac{Y(y_0)}{y_0^{1/\lambda}}. \tag 7$

Comment: Is it possible that there is a less complicated way of obtaining the answer that you've overlooked? Not saying you're wrong, but the other questions in this section of the textbook don't involve anything even close to this level of difficulty and computation. It would be very out of place if this wasn't the case

Comment: At some point you will have to integrate, it's inescapable. Writing the differential equation using log facilitates this but it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: *a less complicated way of obtaining the answer* --- Perhaps this, which has [fewer trees](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=can%27t%20see%20the%20forest%20for%20the%20trees): The $Y$ ordinary differential equation is a first order separable equation: From $\dfrac{dY}{dy} = \dfrac{1}{\lambda y}Y$ we get $\dfrac{dY}{Y} = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\dfrac{dy}{y},$ which can be integrated to give $\ln Y = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\ln y + C = \ln y^{1/\lambda}+C$ (ignoring absolute values). Now exponentiate both sides to get $Y = y^{1/\lambda}\cdot e^C= c_2 y^{1/\lambda}.$

Comment: @Sonjov:  I can't see a "less complicated" way.  You gave me $Y' = Y/(\lambda y)$ and all I really did was note that $Y'/Y = 1/(\lambda y)$ and then that each side has a logaritmic primitive--pretty basic and standard stuff.  What did you find difficult and computationally hard?  If you can be more specific, perhaps I can answer.  Cheers!

Comment: And I don't see how $\ln$ can be avoided sooner or later, after all we have functions of the form $F'(y)/F(y)$, which "invite" or even perhaps "require" $\ln$ to integrate.  What else is there?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{X'}{X} = -\frac 1y \frac{Y}{Y'} = \lambda
$$

so

$$
X(x) = C_1 e^{\lambda x}\\
Y(y) = C_2 y^{-\lambda }
$$

hence

$$
u(x,y) = C_0 \left(\frac{e^x}{y}\right)^{\lambda}
$$

or also

$$
u(x,y) = C_0' \left(y e^{-x}\right)^{\lambda}
$$

considering

$$
\frac{X'}{X} = -\frac 1y \frac{Y}{Y'} = -\lambda
$$